# Permanently open tun0 interface

Tags: network-interface, vpn, openvpn

I have CentOS on the host server and I installed OpenVPN on it.

- When I run

  ```
  openvpn --config config.ovpn
  ```

  `tun0` opens and I can login to the host server from jumpbox server.
- But when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the host server, the command

  ```
  openvpn --config myserver.ovpn
  ```

  terminates and so does the interface `tun0` which kills connection from jumpbox server.

What shall I do to keep `tun0` interface alive?

`iptables` are not running on the server and `netstat` doesn't show 1194 to be opened.

Comment: How about if you set it to run on the background with openvpn --config config.ovpn &

Comment: Even better, run it as a service, so it gets restarted when it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's 2 ways:

1. Run openvpn as a service
2. Detach openvpn from the shell it was started in by appending the command with &

Of these first would be recommended, as running it as a service will autolaunch it in case of failure. Using the second one it needs to be manually re-launched.

Comment: Starting the config as a service and enabling it saved the day:

systemctl enable/start openvpn@myserver

Comment: Thanks for confirming the solution :-)